# split multiple whitespaces from text file to array

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I have a text file and required to have all 7 elements including the empty ones to be parsed into an array for further processing. However, there are no unique delimiter to be make use of except for whitespaces and some of the data/value will come with whitespace. Example per "Data Sample" and some of the block will have null entry. How can i make this happen?

[Snippet of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuPEJ.png)

[Actual Sample Data](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16Re_9A7mkCdK6h6FJFHJ2Gb8VvMWpkETQWA21SmLBp8/edit?usp=sharing)

My end results would be some ting similar like below:

```
Array[0]:123456789
Array[1]:HLTX
Array[2]:5
Array[3]:BT5Q02
Array[4]:4SV
Array[5]:D8041
Array[6]:LIANG LIN
```

My code for the above function for now per below and it will omit the empty values. Which likely will missed out some of the data required.

```
string[] splitlinecontent = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var OrderNum = splitlinecontent[0];
var OrderType = splitlinecontent[1];
int OrderQTY = int.Parse(splitlinecontent[2]);
var OrderSINumInRpt = splitlinecontent[3];
var OrderHoldMod = splitlinecontent[5];
var SalesPerson = splitlinecontent[6];
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please post the sample data as text and not image. so it can be copy poasted. Also I would suggest to use a csv reader which you can find as a nuget package. Use a professional tool developed by people who already solved your problem. don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: Divide the line into substrings and trim the trailing blanks.

Comment: This is a perfect example of how ***not*** to write a record file

Comment: Because you have the headers of the table you know exactly where all the cells of the table are (the first cell is from index 0 to 10 (without the 10th place), the 10th place is the start of the second cell and so on) then you can split each line by the indexes and you have the value of each cell, note that you can trim all the values in the cells this will give you only the text data in each cell (without spaces) and if it is empty (just spaces) it will be empty.

Comment: `String.Split()` has an overload with the *maximum number of entries*. If spaces in the value are always for the last field then specifying a maximum of 7 fields will give you the result you want: `var content = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 7, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries;`.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti will this work if one of the inner values is empty? I think it will change the order in the resulted split

Comment: No, of course it won't work if _inner_ entries are missing but from the data sample I have no reason to believe they could be.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti is right, i have went through thousands of data record and by far, the only possibilities that the column that could have blank values is "Owner" which in this case always be the last column.

Comment: Here's the attached sample data @MongZhu. In actual fact, the sample data does not consists of header.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, i tried your suggestion using String.Split() with overload and this is what i've got and errored me out on the last empty value column:

System.IndexOutOfRangeException
  HResult=0x80131508
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  Source=AutoReleaseConfigSheet
  StackTrace:
   at AutoReleaseConfigSheet.Program.Main() in C:\Users\michael_ng\source\repos\AutoReleaseConfigSheet\Program.cs:line 67

Comment: Just to call out. The output file per attached is not really a CSV formatted file hence i will not get any headers, or delimiters in between each values and columns. The output file was a queried results of upstream applications per mentioned.

Comment: @MichaelNg Given that you're using `RemoveEmptyEntries` if the last column has nothing then you'll get `IndexOutOfRangeException` when trying to read it...just check array length: `string lastField = entries.Length == 7 ? entries[6] : "";`

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, great thanks! I guess that has solved my problem!

this is interesting being a computer science graduate and on job for more than 10 years and never touched on real programming...now that i have find back my way into this...great stuffs!

Answer (score 1):

I think bestpractice for these files is to use TextFieldParser from  Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

```
using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(fileName))
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.FixedWidth;
    parser.SetFieldWidths(3, 7, 10, 13, 8, 6, 1, 7, -1);

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        var fields = parser.ReadFields();
```

But I guess it isn't that hard to code the stuff yourself.

Comment: This is **definitely** the way to go. Don't let the "VisualBasic" in there throw you.

Comment: Worth a try on this. Just that the width or length of the data on that file is not within my realm to control it. Today it may be MAX length in 10 on the first column and it as well could be +1 tomorrow depending on the order number running range. Anyhow, all suggestions are welcome :D

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot of your sample data, your columns have a fixed charsize of ten chars. You now can simply read the sample data line by line and split the lines by this fixed size.

```
public static List<List<string>> GetRecords(string path, bool hasColHeader, int colLength, int colCount){
    //Result will be stored in lists
    List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();

    //Get the sample file
    string[] records = File.ReadAllLines(path,Encoding.UTF8);

    //Go for each line through the data from sample file 
    for(int n = 0; n<records.Length;n++){
        //create new list for this line
        result.Add(new List<string>());

        //here you can do something with headers. for simplification i do nothing with them and continue with next line.
        if(n==0 && hasColHeader){
            continue;
        }

        //go for each column (colCount specifies the count of columns)
        for(int i = 0; i< colCount ;i++){
            
            //if the length of the line is not devisible by colLength, you have to put some spaces to match the columns size
            //not the best way to do this but this is not the major point of this question
            if(records[n].Length % colLength != 0){
                int charsToAdd = (colLength * colCount) - records[n].Length;
                string spaces = "";
                for(int s = 0; s< charsToAdd; s++){
                    spaces += " ";
                }
                records[n] += spaces;
            }

            //add the result to the currently created list
            result[n].Add(records[n].Substring(i*colLength,colLength).Trim());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can use this code like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     List<List<String>> list = GetRecords(@"C:\temp\DataSample.txt",true, 10, 7);
}
```

The data in list looks like this:

```
List[0]:List[0]:123456789
List[0]:List[1]:HLTX
List[0]:List[2]:5
List[0]:List[3]:BT5Q02
List[0]:List[4]:4SV
List[0]:List[5]:D8041
List[0]:List[6]:LIANG LIN
List[1]:List[0]:3835443
List[1]:List[1]:HLTX
List[1]:List[2]:1
...
```

Here you can optimize two things by youreself.

1. Calculate the size of the columns by the chars between headers. The columnsize will alsways be the start of a columnheader and the start of the next columnheader. The charcount between this two points, will be the size of the column.
2. Find a better way to get the last column! :D i dont think what i've done is good. There a better ways to do this.

Comment: your suggestion might work for me just that the actual data set does not consists of column header. The file was a result of an output from another application and my application will be just a feeder to feed in the info on that file and re-process it for other downstream application usages.